# Switching from MSN 6 to Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, browser, bookmarks, windows-live-messenger

Is there anyway to transfer data from MSN 6 to Google Chrome? As far as I can tell, MSN 6 will only save data like favorites as an XML file and Chrome will only import this kind of data as HTML? Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xml can be changed or 'transformed' to html using a 'xslt stylesheet' which is like a small bit of code or a script that reformats the text.  i just went through a whole process of trying to figure it out, it is easy if you only need to make formatting differences, but can get pretty complex with altering the output to varying degrees.  on mac osx 10.5, i used the program 'XSLTPalette' . maybe post the file, or a piece of it and i will try to help, if i can.

Comment: Thanks for offering to help. Here is a copy of the XML code from their favorites file:

Comment: Actually, it won't let me paste all the XML code here. To long. I uploaded it to my server, here's the link. Thanks again for your help! [Favorites.xml](http://ezwebsites.us/TEMP/favorites.xml)

Comment: so everything is a 'favorite' with some attributes and sub-tags. you have to make the sections you want by using 'match' to look for the names of tags you want. then within stylesheet tags, you add whatever html tags you need. the best thing to do would be to get XSLTPalette and some example stylesheets, there are tons out there for html, as i was trying to do xml-rss2.0 and that was all i really saw. so load in your xml file and load an xsltstylesheet into Palette and hit transform and look at the output, make some small changes in the stylesheet and look again...srry i cant be more help

Comment: actually, i just had an idea, since it is just a few entries, why dont you open up the new browser and save some favorites. then open that file to see what the format looks like, and just type up an html in a text editor.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to come back and share your other idea! I love it and it should help a ton. Thanks! +1 :)